# Azure App Service custom deployment (kudu) - permission denied

Tags: azure, kudu

I've an App Service running in Azure, it's only a simple node.js app.

I wanted to use a custom deployment script (because I've to execute npm install in a subdirectory) as it is described here:

- https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments
- https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Custom-Deployment-Script
- https://medium.com/@premchandrasingh/custom-continuous-deployment-script-kudu-for-azure-75217ddcebc5

After uploading the deployment package (via .zip file), the execution of the script "fails".

Reason:

```
/opt/Kudu/bin/Scripts/starter.sh: line 2: /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted/deploy.sh: Permission denied
```

There must be any problem with kudu or the VM of the webapp.

Any idea?

Comment: Am I reading the error message right; starter.sh can't execute deploy.sh? Because of that it throws a "Permission denied" error? If that's the case, what permissions does deploy.sh have? If you `cd` to that its folder and run `ls -l`, then what's the output?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "*After uploading the deployment package (via .zip file)*"? How exactly are you deploying your app?

Comment: @kim yes you're right, permissions are -rwxrwxrwx after i changed it (initially it was -rwxr-xr-x and also didn't work out)
But only on my computer, I have no access via SSH to the VM where the webapp is deployed - there are any connection problems  

@DavidEbbo I did it as described [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deploy-zip)
`az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group myResourceGroup --name <app_name> --src clouddrive/<filename>.zip` is the command  

Zip-File is then deployed automatically by Azure, so the starter.sh runs on the VM

Comment: got exact same error/message for a zip deployment from VSTS/devops, beside having access to SSH of the linux app service, I can't change the permission of deploy.sh because I have no control on it (or I miss something). did you find a workaround ?

Comment: spent a lot of time and still no success, I've created a ticket in kudu github for getting some advices: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2870